# Is there a way to automatticaly reload the page when an <option> from a <select> list is pressed?

Tags: javascript, html, input, drop-down-menu

In a webpage, I have a select HTML list from which the user can select an item and change its price. I put the select and, below, an input text box. Its default value needs to be the current price of the element, so the user can see it and change it. However, when I change the selected item in the dropdown menu, the input text box continues to show the last item's price. I think that by refreshing the page the moment the user clicks the option in the dropdown, this will be fixed, but I don't know how. I hope the doubt was clear enough please tell me if you don't understand something. I would appreciate all your help!!

Comment: use `location.reload()`

Comment: Yes, but I would have to assign it to an option tag in the select dropdown menu and that is not possible

Comment: What do you mean? do you want to reload only when a specific option is pressed, if that was the case then add an event listener for that option element to do that

Comment: No, when any option is pressed, but I can't map an <option> tag to a JS function. EDIT: can I?

Comment: use event delegation instead

Comment: Oh, I'm not familiar with that I'm going to look it up, thanks!

Comment: Why don't you post your code so we can see what's wrong, and I will make sure to write a good and well commented code for you!

Comment: Add an eventlistener 'change' for the select element https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was waiting for you to show some code, but you didn't, so according to your problem you don't need to reload the page, you need to handle the events properly, that's all, so I made this example for you, I have already said that you can use `location.reload` and other stuff, but that was because then I haven't read the body of your question just yet and I was just answering according to the title of the question, anyway here is the example, I have added some comments to make it clear for you to understand the code

```js
// an example of some products and the price of each one
var products = {"ring": 2.54, "watch": 4.99, "necklace": 3.21},
  // get the `<select>` dom element
  productsList = document.querySelector("#products-container select"),
  // get the `<input type="text">` dom element
  productPrice =document.querySelector("#products-container input");

// set the value of the price input to the first product's price
productPrice.value = Object.values(products)[0];

// loop over the products and create an option for each one
for(var product in products) {
  productsList.innerHTML += `<option value="${product}">${product}</option>`;
}

// when the user chooses a product we show its price on the price input
productsList.onchange = function() {
  productPrice.value = products[this.value];
}

// when the user changes the price of an element we save that into our object of elements
productPrice.onchange = function() {
  products[productsList.value] = this.value;
}
```

```html
<div id="products-container">
  <select>
  </select>
  <input type="text">
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, seriously. No one has ever helped me more than you have done today. I would vote for your answer but i don't have the reputation to do so yet. Thank you!!!!!!!

Comment: If that helped you then just mark it as answer by checking the green mark, so anyone has the same problem can find the answer quickly, and I'm glad I could help, happy coding!